# PHP - Connecting to MySQL Turnkey Linux

Tags: php, mysql

I have probably an incredible stupid question...

I have the following code, it should work. All credentials are working, I tested them with a different script.
But, I cant see where the code is wrong...

Could someone be so kind to help me in finding the problem, so I can understand it better?

```
define("HOST", "localhost"); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "deb63058_DomiSec"); // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "ypPN7UY6aaxLxw7D6qwTrkJ3"); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "deb63058_Domi"); // The database name.

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE) ;
// If you are connecting via TCP/IP rather than a UNIX socket remember to add the port number as a parameter.

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","deb63058_DomiSec","ypPN7UY6aaxLxw7D6qwTrkJ3","deb63058_Domi");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL !!!: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Give's the following error:

```
Failed to connect to MySQL !!!: Access denied for user 'deb63058_DomiSec'@'%' to database 'deb63058_Domi'
```

What does '@'%' mean in the error message?
I connect to a local turnkey linux server

Comment: `Access denied for user` is a simple username/password error message - check your username and password. Normally that would say : Denied for user 'deb63058_DomiSec'@'**localhost**' though. ... I hope none of those connection details are really, real though (on a public website like SO)

Comment: ... oh, also check your `mysql`.`user` and `mysql`.`tables_priv` tables to ensure that your user has access rights to the `deb63058_Domi` table

Answer (score 3):

`'deb63058_DomiSec'@'%'` means the user has been created so that it can access the database from any host. % is a mysql wildcard. The error `Access denied for user 'deb63058_DomiSec'@'%' to database 'deb63058_Domi'` indicates that the password is correct, but the user does not have access to that database. Check the privs for that user within mysql with this command: `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'deb63058_DomiSec'@'%';`  Then add the necessary privs that you need.

Comment: Just checked it in MySQL Workbench, your absolutely right! Thank you very much aynber, I was seeking the error in PHP...